Trace formula in Grassmann algebra
From Grassmann algebra, we know the following relation
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Tr} e^{-a\hat{c}^{\dagger}\hat{c}} =1+e^{-a}
\end{equation}
Now, how to prove the following generalized results?
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Tr} e^{-\textbf{A}} =\mathrm{Det} (I+e^{-[A]})
\end{equation}
where $A=\sum_{ij} A_{ij}c^{\dagger}_{i}c_{j}$ and $i,j=1 \cdots L$, and $[A]$ is the $L\times L$ matrix $A_{ij}$

Is this from a reference? Which page?

WP.

Have you checked the L =2 case?

We can diagonalize the A and follow the usual procedure to obtain the answer.
